# MYSQL: Convert String between two characters to integer

Tags: mysql, string, integer, substring, extract

I have a string column that varies in length and content, examples include...

> $5,000 (USA) (23 October 2011)
>
> $981,000 (USA) (1933)
>
> $560 (USA)

It always begins with $, and the initial figure is always followed by ' (USA)'.

What I want to do is to extract the dollar figure and place it into a new column as an integer.

> $5,000 (USA) (23 October 2011)
>
> becomes 5000

I presume I need MYSQL to locate the figure between the '$' and the ' (USA)', remove the ',' and dump it into a new columnn.The closest I've gotten is using

```
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, '(',+1)
```

Which reliably cuts out everything after the figure....

> $5,000 (USA) (23 October 2011)
>
> becomes $5,000

but how do I finish up? I'm very new to MYSQL so any input would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following

```
mysql> select * from test ;
+--------------------------------+--------+
| val                            | amount |
+--------------------------------+--------+
| $5,000 (USA) (23 October 2011) |   NULL |
| $981,000 (USA) (1933)          |   NULL |
+--------------------------------+--------+
```

Now using the following update command the `amount` column will be updated with the amount value from string as

```
update test 
set amount = replace(replace(substring_index(val,'(USA)',1),'$',''),',','') ;

mysql> select * from test ;
+--------------------------------+--------+
| val                            | amount |
+--------------------------------+--------+
| $5,000 (USA) (23 October 2011) |   5000 |
| $981,000 (USA) (1933)          | 981000 |
+--------------------------------+--------+
```

Comment: what happen if amount is 7 digit number

Comment: It does not matter how big is the number it will extract that, now it depends on `int` datatype limit, if its going beyond that then perhaps the column needs to be as `bigint`

Comment: This looks great! I'll give it a go later and report back.

Comment: I didn't want to make a new field but I used replace(replace(substring_index(val,'(USA)',1),'$',''),',','') as part of a SELECT query and it generated a new column for me to export as needed. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST( REPLACE( REPLACE( SUBSTRING_INDEX(  '$5,000(USD)',  '(' , +1 ) ,  '$',  '' ) ,  ',',  '' ) AS UNSIGNED )
```

Comment: This was similar to Abhik's answer, but it wasn't clear what CAST would have done for me. It helped me in conjunction with the top answer though.